# Loops causing my program to crash (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, loops

I'm newish to VB and I'm having some issues. I'm using Repeat Until loops and my program is just crashing if I try to put anything of minor complexity in. I'm generating random numbers. I've isolated the issue to the following loop, and have removed other code that doesn't effect it.

ShowNO, Hidden, C, CA, R, RA, B, BA and all the B11 etc. values are defined as integers.

Hidden is confined to the range 11-19 in the HSB, so that aint the issue

```
Hidden = hsbDifficulty.Value * -1
If (Hidden = 11 Or 12) Then
        RA = 5
        CA = 5
        BA = 5
    End If
    If (Hidden = 13 Or 14) Then
        RA = 5
        CA = 5
        BA = 6
    End If
    If (Hidden = 15 Or 16 Or 17) Then
        RA = 5
        CA = 6
        BA = 6
    End If
    If (Hidden = 18 Or 19) Then
        RA = 6
        CA = 6
        BA = 6
    End If
Randomize()
Do
        Do
            ShowNO = (Rnd() * 36)
            Select Case ShowNO
                Case Is = 0
                    B66 = 1
                Case Is = 1
                    B11 = 1
                Case Is = 2
                    B12 = 1
                Case Is = 3
                    B13 = 1
                Case Is = 4
                    B14 = 1
                Case Is = 5
                    B15 = 1
                Case Is = 6
                    B16 = 1
                Case Is = 7
                    B21 = 1
                Case Is = 8
                    B22 = 1
                Case Is = 9
                    B23 = 1
                Case Is = 10
                    B24 = 1
                Case Is = 11
                    B25 = 1
                Case Is = 12
                    B26 = 1
                Case Is = 13
                    B31 = 1
                Case Is = 14
                    B32 = 1
                Case Is = 15
                    B33 = 1
                Case Is = 16
                    B34 = 1
                Case Is = 17
                    B35 = 1
                Case Is = 18
                    B36 = 1
                Case Is = 19
                    B41 = 1
                Case Is = 20
                    B42 = 1
                Case Is = 21
                    B43 = 1
                Case Is = 22
                    B44 = 1
                Case Is = 23
                    B45 = 1
                Case Is = 24
                    B46 = 1
                Case Is = 25
                    B51 = 1
                Case Is = 26
                    B52 = 1
                Case Is = 27
                    B53 = 1
                Case Is = 28
                    B54 = 1
                Case Is = 29
                    B55 = 1
                Case Is = 30
                    B56 = 1
                Case Is = 31
                    B61 = 1
                Case Is = 32
                    B62 = 1
                Case Is = 33
                    B63 = 1
                Case Is = 34
                    B64 = 1
                Case Is = 35
                    B65 = 1
                Case Is = 36
                    B66 = 1
            End Select
        Loop Until (B11 + B12 + B13 + B14 + B15 + B16 + B21 + B22 + B23 + B24 + B25 + B26 + B31 + B32 + B33 + B34 + B35 + B36 + B41 + B42 + B43 + B44 + B45 + B46 + B51 + B52 + B53 + B54 + B55 + B56 + B61 + B62 + B63 + B64 + B65 + B66 = Hidden)
        If (B11 + B12 + B13 + B14 + B15 + B16 > 0.9) Then
            R = R + 1
        End If
        If (B21 + B22 + B23 + B24 + B25 + B26 > 0.9) Then
            R = R + 1
        End If
        If (B31 + B32 + B33 + B34 + B35 + B36 > 0.9) Then
            R = R + 1
        End If
        If (B41 + B42 + B43 + B44 + B45 + B46 > 0.9) Then
            R = R + 1
        End If
        If (B51 + B52 + B53 + B54 + B55 + B56 > 0.9) Then
            R = R + 1
        End If
        If (B61 + B62 + B63 + B64 + B65 + B66 > 0.9) Then
            R = R + 1
        End If
        If (B11 + B21 + B31 + B41 + B51 + B61 > 0.9) Then
            C = C + 1
        End If
        If (B12 + B22 + B32 + B42 + B52 + B62 > 0.9) Then
            C = C + 1
        End If
        If (B13 + B23 + B33 + B43 + B53 + B63 > 0.9) Then
            C = C + 1
        End If
        If (B14 + B24 + B34 + B44 + B54 + B64 > 0.9) Then
            C = C + 1
        End If
        If (B15 + B25 + B35 + B45 + B55 + B65 > 0.9) Then
            C = C + 1
        End If
        If (B16 + B26 + B36 + B46 + B56 + B66 > 0.9) Then
            C = C + 1
        End If
        If (B11 + B12 + B13 + B21 + B22 + B23 > 0.9) Then
            B = B + 1
        End If
        If (B31 + B32 + B33 + B41 + B42 + B43 > 0.9) Then
            B = B + 1
        End If
        If (B51 + B52 + B53 + B61 + B62 + B63 > 0.9) Then
            B = B + 1
        End If
        If (B14 + B15 + B16 + B24 + B25 + B26 > 0.9) Then
            B = B + 1
        End If
        If (B34 + B35 + B36 + B44 + B45 + B46 > 0.9) Then
            B = B + 1
        End If
        If (B54 + B55 + B56 + B64 + B65 + B66 > 0.9) Then
            B = B + 1
        End If
    Loop Until (B > (BA - 1) And C > (CA - 1) And R > (RA - 1))
```

Comment: Though not related to the error u r facing, you likely need to introduce an array instead of using a big carton of variables. That will help u isolate the problem more easily.

Comment: _*Analyzing......*_ (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ All I can say is `Infinite Loop` by the looks of it!

Comment: It shouldn't be infinite as it works about 1/10 times and spits out its variables and subsequently applies the respective properties to the user txt input boxes. (1 - Read Only, 0 - Not Read Only)

Comment: Now I know who wrote the code for my current project. That is just way too many variables. I can't even follow what is going on. :/

Comment: "Crash" is usually a very broad term. There is no exception? Just the program disappears?

Comment: Your program crashing can be an indication of an `Infinite loop`. You are using a random numbers that can mean in some numbers it will be fine and in some it means _anarchy_.

Comment: The program locks up and refuses to respond. I've tried leaving it for a while and same deal.

RE: Random numbers - The RND function generates a random number between 0 and 1, this is then multiplied up to 36, and with the integer property of variables, it rounds it to a whole number. 

The reason why I have shit loads of variables is that I have loads of output objects, 36 in fact. It's required for the project as part of my course. I'll try and re-jig it into an array and see and then extract values from that to form my boxes and perform the  checks to ensure the combination is valid.

Comment: your 4 ifs (beginning with "If (Hidden = 11 Or 12) Then" are confusing ... I try to get this working for me as test: Please try this, and you will understand how confusing your code is:            Dim hidden As Integer = 17
        Dim whatever As Integer

        whatever = (hidden = 11 Or 12)

        If (hidden = 11 Or 12) Then
            Console.WriteLine("hidden = 11 or 12 - but thats wrong")
        End If

        If whatever Then
            Console.WriteLine("whatever is true")
        End If

Comment: Switch `Option Strict On` if you haven't already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-jigged the whole thing to an array which fixed the problem. Likely the huge amount of variables that made it crash. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-be/library/cy37t14y.aspx) for `Select Case` in VB .Net, you will find out that you are doint it wrong :

```
Select Case ShowNo
    'Use Case 0 Instead of Case Is = 0
    Case 0
        'Do some Stuff
End Select
```

Also, as mentionned by nabuchodonossor, the `If` at the begginning are not good :

```
'Proper way to write this :
If Hidden = 11 Or Hidden = 12 Then
```

Also, if you can give us the Exception that you encouter, we might be able to help you better.